# Seconds ignored when fetching MySQL datetime field in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, parsing

I'm stuck in what seems to be a very silly problem: I'm using both mysql.connector and MySQLdb to retrieve some datetime data, when I fetchall() values to put them on an array, I need to parse each row, but when the datetime has any "double zeros" as seconds, that part of the datetime is ignored and my parsing fails. Here's the scenario:

```
mycursor.execute("select arrival_time from queue_element where status='Pending'")
arrival = mycursor.fetchall()
```

let's say it returns two rows:

```
>> arrival
>> [(datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 7, 2, 45, 48),), (datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 7, 2, 46),)]
In the database:

2019-10-07 02:45:48 
2019-10-07 02:46:00
```

So when I try to parse it with datetime.datetime, the rows that only posseses 5 values, with the seconds being ignored instead of displayed as 00, fails and my code breaks. Here's how I'm trying to achieve this:

```
for item in arrival:
    arrival_parsed = str(item).replace("(datetime.datetime(", "") # extracts only the numbers
    arrival_parsed = str(arrival_parsed).replace("),)", "") # extracts only the numbers
    arrival_parsed = str(datetime.strptime(arrival_parsed,'%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S')) # works fine if seconds != 00, breaks if equal
The error:

ValueError: time data '2019, 10, 7, 2, 46' does not match format '%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S'
```

Tried to play with datetime but no luck. Any hints on how to parse it correctly or retrieve the value with the zeros?

Thanks!

Comment: When you apply `str()` to a `datetime` instance, it returns only the "numbers" so `replace()` method does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple if-else condition can do the trick. Try with the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
arrival = [(datetime(2019, 10, 7, 2, 45, 48),), (datetime(2019, 10, 7, 2, 46),)]

for item in arrival:
  if item[0].second != 0:
    arrival_parsed = str(item).replace("(datetime.datetime(", "") # extracts only the numbers
    arrival_parsed = str(arrival_parsed).replace("),)", "") # extracts only the numbers
    arrival_parsed = str(datetime.strptime(arrival_parsed,'%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S'))
    print(arrival_parsed)
  else:
    arrival_parsed = str(item).replace("(datetime.datetime(", "") # extracts only the numbers
    arrival_parsed = str(arrival_parsed).replace("),)", "") # extracts only the numbers
    arrival_parsed =  arrival_parsed + ", 0"
    arrival_parsed = str(datetime.strptime(arrival_parsed,'%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S'))
    print(arrival_parsed)
```

Comment: I thought about making a if statement but couldn't get to the last element as you did with item[0].second. Works like a charm, thank you!